# Show Most Frequently Occurring Text With Criteria

Tags: excel, indexing, excel-formula, match

[image]My data set is something like this (below). Column C is what I'm attempting to get. I want column C to show the most frequently occurring value for each Group. It must ignore instances where there is no value in the "Fruit" column. In instances where there's a tie, column C simply chooses one of the values.

```
Group       Fruit   Most Freq Occurring
Group A     Apple   Apple
Group A     Apple   Apple
Group A     Pear    Apple
Group B     Apple   Apple
Group B     Pear    Apple
Group B     Apple   Apple
Group B     Pear    Apple
```

Comment: Ive tried index mode match, with an if statement, to no avail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming the table as you give it is in `A1:C8`, array formula** in `C2`:

`=INDEX(B$2:B$8,MODE(IF(A$2:A$8=A2,IF(B$2:B$8<>"",MATCH(B$2:B$8,B$2:B$8,{0,0})))))`

Copy down as required.

I used `{0,0}` in place of the standard `0` for `MATCH`'s *match_type* parameter so that, in cases where no one value occurs more than once, the construction does not error.

An alternative, non-CSE set-up is:

`=LOOKUP(1,0/FREQUENCY(0,1/(1+COUNTIFS(A$2:A$8,A2,B$2:B$8,B$2:B$8,B$2:B$8,"<>"))),B$2:B$8)`

Regards

***Array formulas are not entered in the same way as 'standard' formulas. Instead of pressing just ENTER, you first hold down CTRL and SHIFT, and only then press ENTER. If you've done it correctly, you'll notice Excel puts curly brackets {} around the formula (though do not attempt to manually insert these yourself).*

Comment: I tried both formulas entered as arrays. Both are showing only one value in Column C though, by spot-checking the data, results should have varying values across groups. I tested and it appears both formulas are only selecting the most frequently occurring fruit for the first group and applying that value in column C for all subsequent groups. In other words, the entire Column C appears to only be evaluating Group A only.

Comment: I trust you followed the instructions given, i.e. to enter the formula in cell C2 and then copy down? When you say that you entered them "as arrays", I trust you don't mean MULTI-CELL array formulas, which of course is not at all what I instructed.

Comment: This works perfectly. A side note; if you'll write this formula and drag it down make sure you lock the arrays using $ correctly.